# SwiftUI - Pop up Image/Text

Tags: xcode, swiftui

I am writing a game (my first) and I have the board set up and the code works for the game. I am using SwiftUI to stack the main screen. I am now wanting to pop up a text/image when the player drops a letter. I have seen in lots of games, but cannot find any help or instruction on how it is done.

```
    import SwiftUI


struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showLetters = [String](repeating: "Blank", count: 36)
    @State private var testLetters = [String](repeating: "Blank", count: 7)
    @State private var originalLetters = [String](repeating: "Blank", count: 7)
    @State private var tray = [String](repeating: "Blank", count: 7)
    @State private var buttonFrames = [CGRect](repeating: .zero, count: 35)
    @State private var score = 0
    @State private var lineNo = 0

    @State var displayItem: Int = -1

    let allowedWords = Bundle.main.words(from: "words.txt")

    var body: some View {


        VStack(spacing: 5) {

            Image("word5sm")


            HStack {
                ForEach(0..<7) { number in
                    Letter(text: self.showLetters[number], index: number, onChanged: self.letterMoved, onEnded: self.letterDropped)
                        .allowsHitTesting(false)
                        .overlay(
                            GeometryReader { geo in
                                Color.clear
                                    .onAppear {
                                        self.buttonFrames[number] = geo.frame(in: .global)

                                    }
                            }
                        )


                }


            }


            HStack {ForEach(7..<14) { number in
                Letter(text: self.showLetters[number], index: number, onChanged: self.letterMoved, onEnded: self.letterDropped)
                                   .allowsHitTesting(false)
                                   .overlay(
                                       GeometryReader { geo in
                                           Color.clear
                                               .onAppear {
                                                  self.buttonFrames[number] = geo.frame(in: .global)
                                               }
                                       }
                                   )
                }
            }


            HStack {ForEach(14..<21) { number in
                Letter(text: self.showLetters[number], index: number, onChanged: self.letterMoved, onEnded: self.letterDropped)
                                   .allowsHitTesting(false)
                                   .overlay(
                                       GeometryReader { geo in
                                           Color.clear
                                               .onAppear {
                                                  self.buttonFrames[number] = geo.frame(in: .global)
                                               }
                                       }
                                   )
                }
            }

            HStack {ForEach(21..<28) { number in
                Letter(text: self.showLetters[number], index: number, onChanged: self.letterMoved, onEnded: self.letterDropped)
                                   .allowsHitTesting(false)
                                   .overlay(
                                       GeometryReader { geo in
                                           Color.clear
                                               .onAppear {
                                                  self.buttonFrames[number] = geo.frame(in: .global)
                                               }
                                       }
                                   )
                }
            }

            HStack {ForEach(28..<35) { number in
                Letter(text: self.showLetters[number], index: number, onChanged: self.letterMoved, onEnded: self.letterDropped)
                                   .allowsHitTesting(false)
                                   .overlay(
                                       GeometryReader { geo in
                                           Color.clear
                                               .onAppear {
                                                  self.buttonFrames[number] = geo.frame(in: .global)
                                               }
                                       }
                                   )
                }
            }

            HStack {

                    ResetButton {
                        self.returnLetters()
                    }

                    NewLine {
                        self.newLine()
                    }

                    CalcButton {
                        self.calcButton()
                    }

                   }

            HStack {
                ForEach(0..<7) { number in
                    Letter(text: self.tray[number], index: number, onChanged: self.letterMoved, onEnded: self.letterDropped)

                }


            }




        }
        .frame(width: 768, height: 856)
        .background(Image("Background"))
        .onAppear(perform: startGame)
        .allowsHitTesting(true)

        }



This is my code for the main screen....
```

this is the sort pop thing I am trying to get, with a text that pops up.

[image: Pop Up Message]

Comment: You could use a `ZStack` with an `if` statement, which shows or hides `Text` according to a `Bool` state. Use `transition` to add fancy animations... Your example obviously does not work for me since you provided not all the code needed to run it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may have misunderstood what you asked for. I cannot use your example so I had to make my own:

This makes use of `ZStack` to draw `Text` on top of the `GameView` via a `transition`... note the `withAnimation` block to activate the transition.

```
struct GameView: View {
    @Binding var showText: Bool
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
            .frame(width: 80, height: 180)
            Circle()
                .foregroundColor(.red)
            .frame(width: 50)
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(.green)
            .frame(width: 150, height: 110)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @State var showText = false

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                GameView(showText: self.$showText)
                Button(action: {
                    withAnimation {
                        self.showText.toggle()
                    }
                }, label: {
                    Text("Show / Hide Text")
                })
            }
            if self.showText {
                VStack {
                    Spacer()
                    HStack {
                        Spacer()
                        Text("Hello I am a Text")
                            .foregroundColor(.orange)
                            .font(.system(.largeTitle))
                            .transition(.opacity)
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, ideal, and understand how its working. Thanks again

Comment: This works nicely and i can use Image instead of text too. Question, i have some functions outside GameView or ContentView, how would I (can i) change the showText bool from within these functions?

Comment: this depends where they are... if this answers your question please accept it. If you have another question please ask a new one. @Lynxbci

Comment: Accepted with thanks. The functions are all within GameView, but i cannot set showtext from within Gameview it seems. I will try and post a new question, but not sure what i am asking lol

Comment: use `Binding` in `GameView` and pass it from the `ContentView`... then you can change it within!

Comment: @Lynxbci I edited the answer so you have the binding example included!

Comment: Perfect. every day is a school day. Thank you for your help. Much appreciated