# Toggle a var from a different View

Tags: xcode, swiftui

In my ContentView i have a Zstack image, that has a var showText that i can toggle on and off using the button created.

```
     struct ContentView: View {

    @State var showText = true
    @State var attempts: Int = 0

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {

        VStack {
            GameView()
            Button(action: {
                withAnimation {
                    self.showText.toggle()
                    self.attempts += 1
                }
            }, label: {
                Text("Show / Hide Text")
            })
        }
            if self.showText {
                VStack {
                    Spacer()
                    HStack {
                        Spacer()
                        Image("word5sm")
                        .modifier(Shake(animatableData: CGFloat(attempts)))

                        Spacer()
                    }
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    }

struct GameView: View {

    @State private var showLetters = ...... etc etc
```

However, i do not want a button in ContentView. I want to toggle this variable from my GameView. So when the user adds a tile to the game it can pop up the image.

How do i toggle the var that is set in ContentView from GameView ??

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I actually just edited the original question, where you asked in the comments:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/59863781/5981293

I added a `Button` inside the `GameView` which now toggles the `Binding` you pass in.

You can use `@Binding` for this:

```
struct GameView: View {
    @Binding var showText: Bool
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
            .frame(width: 80, height: 180)
            Circle()
                .foregroundColor(.red)
            .frame(width: 50)
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(.green)
            .frame(width: 150, height: 110)
            Button(action: {
                withAnimation {
                    self.showText.toggle()
                }
            }, label: {
                Text("Toggle from within GameView")
            })
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @State var showText = false

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                GameView(showText: self.$showText)
                Button(action: {
                    withAnimation {
                        self.showText.toggle()
                    }
                }, label: {
                    Text("Show / Hide Text")
                })
            }
            if self.showText {
                VStack {
                    Spacer()
                    HStack {
                        Spacer()
                        Text("Hello I am a Text")
                            .foregroundColor(.orange)
                            .font(.system(.largeTitle))
                            .transition(.opacity)
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Thanks for asking again!